# Dependency Injection in abstract class, ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

In my ASP.NET Core 2 project, I create new class that inherits the **RazorPage** class to add some additional property in views.

```cs
public abstract class WebViewPage<TModel> : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<TModel>
{
    public string Version
    {
        get
        {
            return "1.00.100";
        }
    }
    public User CurrentUser
    {
        get
        {
            //challenge is here:
            //return _services.GetRequiredService<IUserService>().GetCurrentUser();
        }
    }
}

public abstract class WebViewPage : WebViewPage<dynamic>
{

}
```

and `_ViewImport.cshtml` file changed to this:

```
@inherits MyProject.WebViewPage<TModel>
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

The project works fine till challenge codes are marked as comment. but, how can I inject dependencies to the abstract class? or how to Resolve services in abstract class?

This is my `StartUp.cs` file:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();
        //services.AddScoped<IRazorPage<?>, WebViewPage<?>(); // ?: challenge!
}
```

Comment: I'd imagine you can create a constructor that asks for the dependencies as you can do with any class? Have you tried that?

Comment: You can't instantiate abstract classes, hence you can't use it for registration. You always have to use **concerete** classes

Comment: @Tseng do you have a reference for your comment that DI doesnt apply to abstract classes?

Comment: @JayJayJay: C# (or OOP in general) basics. [abstract class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract#example). How do you want to instanciate abstract class? it only provides a base implementation. to instantiate it you need a **concrete** type/implementation which inherits from the base class. as such you need to register the derieved classes, one by one.

Comment: .NET Core's DI (`Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`) doesn't support assembly or type scanning as other IoC containers do, so you can't register "all types which derieve from Y" in a single call. you'll have to use reflection, bit of LINQ (or for/foreach looping) to filter it and then register the derived types in a loop. Built-in IoC is meant to be simple and work out of the box and that you can plug-in 3rd party containers with extended features (such as scanning or auto register types which derive from Y)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need access to the service provider inside of your razor page, you could access the `HttpContext` through the [`Context` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.razorpage.context), e.g.:

```
var userService = Context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUserService>();
```

A possibly better alternative would be to have a constructor that takes the `IUserService` as a dependency. So implementations of your type would have to pass that dependency on, essentially requiring them to have a constructor dependency on their own (which makes a good explicit design).

---

As for that dependency registration part, note that you generally cannot register abstract classes because they cannot be instantiated.

But in general, in order to register a generic type, you have to use the more verbose overload of `AddScoped` which takes actual `Type` arguments:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRazorPage<>), typeof(WebViewPage<>));
```

Making a generic method call requires a real type as a generic type argument, so you would have to specify a concrete type for the type argument `T` inside `IRazorPage<T>` and `WebViewPage<T>`. Since you explicitly do not want to use a concrete type there but instead want to tell the dependency injection container to support *any* type, you cannot use this syntax there.

Since the `typeof` operator can determine the actual *generic* type, you can use it without having to use a specific type argument which would limit the registration to a single type.

Comment: How does this answer how to inject the services *into* `WebViewPage`? In fact, I don't think that adding `WebViewPage` into the container is needed

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I understood OP in that they did not know how to register `WebViewPage` as their implementation given that commented-out line in their shown `Startup`.

Comment: I understand that the actual problem lies on "//challenge is here:
            //return _services.GetRequiredService<IUserService>().GetCurrentUser();" That's why my comment on the question

Comment: Thanks, but exceptionally in this question, I can access to **Context**, because its defined in **RazorPage** class!

Comment: @SalehBagheri Yes, you can access `Context` because it is defined in `RazorPage` and your type is inheriting from it.

Comment: Is there any general way to access services (resolving services) in an abstract class?

Comment: Yes, by injecting them. And no, there is (by design) no static way to access services if that’s what you mean.